# How to handle NetworkStream.Write failure

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I have two applications a server and a client. I can send messages between the two as long as they are both running.

When I close the server and try to send a message with NetworkStream.Write i get an exception.

What would be the best way to handle this and notify the client that the server is down?

Comment: What client?  If she's human then use, say, MessageBox to tell her about the server being rude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ping is a bad idea. The connection can go down between the ping and the actual message too.

As you yourself pointed out:

wrap the write in a try/catch and display a nice little message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You could ping the server prior to sending the message, if the ping fails then inform the user and don't send the message etc.

Comment: Pointless. Just send the message, and if *it* fails then inform the user.

Comment: And to check the failure is putting NetworkStream.Write inside try catch enough? Looks like I can check if I get an IOException.